# A simple search-and-replace algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

In recent times, I've been using the following algorithm repeatedly in different languages (Java, Python, ...) to search and replace strings. I don't like this implementation very much, it's very procedural and not very descriptive, but I have yet to come up with a better one. How could the implementation be improved?

```py
from typing import Callable
import re

def find_and_replace(pattern: str, text: str, replace: Callable[[re.Match], str]) -> str:
    last_end = 0
    output = []
    for match in pattern.finditer(text):
        text_before = text[last_end:match.start()]
        if text_before:
            output.append(text_before)
        replacement = replace(match)
        output.append(replacement)
        last_end = end
    text_remaining = text[last_end:]
    if text_remaining:
        output.append(text_remaining)
    return ''.join(output)
```

Comment: Where does `PATTERN` come from?  And are you missing any imports? (`re` perhaps?)

Comment: Your question is hard to answer, because "improve" and "very procedural and not very descriptive" are rather opinions. What exactly would you expect from improved code? That said, `PATTERN` should obviously be a parameter and the checks to not append empty strings to `output` are redundant. Apart from that, the implementation is easy to follow, so nothing I would obsess about.

Comment: @TobySpeight I left out imports for simplicity. Of course, `re` and `typing.Callable` need to be imported. And `PATTERN` should be a parameter, as @uli correctly pointed out. I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: This won't run. `end` is undefined. Don't omit important code for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: You also need to show how this is used.

Comment: What logic is contained in the `replace` function? Is it conditional on the old capture value?

Comment: I have to apologize, I should definitely test my code before posting it! Just fixed it in a way that @J_H's answer is still valid.

Comment: Please read the "_What should I **not** do?_" part of the site [guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Edits after a review are subject to being rolled back, so folks can see the code the review applies to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## wrong signature

```
def find_and_replace(pattern: str, ...
```

You intended `pattern: re.Pattern,`

Recommend you routinely use `mypy` or similar type checker
if you choose to add optional type annotations.

It is common knowledge that "Comments lie!".
Often they're initially accurate,
and then the code evolves with edits
while the comments remain mired in the past, out of sync.
So at best we will "mostly believe" the comments that appear.

A type signature offers stronger promises, since we expect
that lint nonsense was cleaned up during routine edit-debug
and CI/CD cycles. Posting code for review which doesn't meet that
expectation is problematic.

## wrong code

```
        last_end = end
```

You intended to assign `... = match.end()`.
I cannot imagine how one could "test" this source code
without noticing a fatal NameError.

## missing documentation

The review context merely mentioned that this will "search and replace strings",
similar to what the identifier promises.
It's unclear how the proposed functionality would differ from what the
[str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) or
[re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)
libraries offer, though the signature *does* offer a hint.
The hint is not enough, and we are not even offered so
much as a motivating example of the kinds of Turing machines
we might usefully pass in.

## missing test suite

This submission contained no doctest, no automated tests of any kind.
One reason we write tests is to exercise the code,
for example to discover a NameError.
Another reason is to educate engineers who might want
to call into this library routine.

Here is *a* test that might usefully have been included in the OP.

```
import unittest

class FindAndReplaceTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_find_and_replace(self) -> None:
        pattern = re.compile(r"\w+")
        text = "... Hello, world!"

        def replace(match: re.Match) -> str:
            return "<" + str(match.group(0).upper()) + ">"

        self.assertEqual(
            "... <HELLO>, <WORLD>!",
            find_and_replace(pattern, text, replace),
        )
```

## superfluous tests

```
        if text_before:
            output.append(text_before)
        ...
    if text_remaining:
        output.append(text_remaining)
```

There's no need to test for non-empty,
as empty string is the additive identity when catenating.
The `''.join(output)` result won't be altered in the
slightest if we tack on a hundred empty entries with:

```
    output += [""] * 100
```

So as a minor cleanup, simply elide the `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all of this, and wherever it was called, replace with stock [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of `pattern`. The function takes a single `Match` argument, and returns the replacement string.